# Siri should open certain Page or ViewController

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10, siri, sirikit

My app is a self care app. In this app user can pay his bills once he is logged in. I am able to open the app successfully via Siri. Just wondering if I could pay the bills via SIRI

1. While opening the app I could do login in background with saved user credentials in app.
2. In Payment intent handler I can send the payment response to SIRI.

Answer (score -1):

In iOS 10 there are two different uses for Siri.  Sirikit is to register intents, such as booking a ride or making personal payments.  The intents are limited to what Apple has outlined here although I am sure they will expand in the future:
https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/

The other is to use Speech Framework to transcribe speech to text.  You can do whatever you want with that input, but it only works if the user opens the app and then you initiate Speech recognition.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech

Comment: This answer is not relevant to question